# Start irexec on boot with a script

Tags: 12.10, xbmc, ubuntu-minimal, lirc

I created a file in `/etc/init.d/startirexec.sh` with the contents:

```
#! /bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          irexec
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts instance of irexec
# Description:       starts instance of irexec
### END INIT INFO

irexec -d
exit 0
```

I then do a

```
sudo chmod +x startirexec.sh
sudo update-rc.d startirexec.sh defaults
```

Everything seems to go ok. I reboot but `irexec` is not loaded.  If I do a

```
sudo ./startirexec.sh
```

manually it loads just fine.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UDEV to start programs such as irexec when a remote control is added, such as a MCE receiver.

Create a UDEV rule:

> sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/irexec.rules

And paste in the following:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="rc", RUN+="/usr/bin/irexec -d"
```

The [Udev man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) contains more information for putting together more advanced rules.